# How to save Hashset to file in Android?

Tags: java, android, hashset

I'm trying to export a Hashset (integer) to file with the following code but it appears I can't use `outputStream.write()` to do it. There don't seem to be any previous questions here or on google that cover it which surprises me.

Hashset is defined in the Activity as:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

and Method is:

```
    public void savehashset(){
    String filename="storedhashset.set";
    File storedhashset = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      outputStream.write(set);
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why cannnot you use it? Have you checked your app has permissions to write files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to serialize your `HashSet` on a file. For this purpose you can use an `ObjectOutputStream`

```
try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
      oos.writeObject(set);
      oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

From the doc of [writeObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Writes an object to the target stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am I able to read it in using `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream); set =ois.readObject();`
It seems like I'm not able to convert the object?

Answer (score 0):

Since HashSet implements Serializable, you can try this:

```
ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(
                            new FileOutputStream("object.data"));

HashSet<Integer> object = new HashSet<Integer>();

output.writeObject(object);
//etc.

output.close();
```